# Scrapy crawlspider does not follow links

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to make a crawler that will crawl an entire website and output a list of all the domains that the said websites links to (without duplicates).

I have come up with the following code :

```
import scrapy
from crawler.items import CrawlerItem
from crawler.functions import urlToDomain
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class domainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    global allDomains
    allDomains = []
    name = "domainSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://example.com/"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):

        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        # formating all URL formats to the same one (https://url.com)
        urlsOk = []
        for elt in urls :
            if elt [:2] == "//" : # link is external, append http
                urlsOk.append(elt)
            elif elt[:4] == "http" :
                urlsOk.append(elt)

        domaines = list(set([urlToDomain(x) for x in urlsOk]))
        item = CrawlerItem()
        item["domaines"] = []
        item["url"] = response.url
        for elt in domaines:
            if elt not in allDomains :
                item['domaines'].append(elt)
                allDomains.append(elt)

                yield({
                    'domaines':elt

                })
```

This is workinge exactly like expected in retrieving the domains, but it stops crawling (finished) after the very first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overriding a built-in CrawlSpider method (`parse`) which caused the bug...

The solution was to change the callback method's name from `parse` to anything else.

[image]